# Read a JSON file containing unicode data

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

Here is the content of my JSON file

```
cat ./myfile.json

{u'Records': [{u'eventVersion': u'2.0', }]}
```

How do I read this JSON file?

I tried reading the file with the following code,

```
def Read_json_file(jsonFile):
   jsonDy = {}
   if os.path.exists(jsonFile):
      with open(jsonFile, 'rt') as fin:
         jsonDy = json.load(fin)
   else:
      print("JSON file not available ->",
                                 jsonFile)
      sys.exit(1)
   print("jsonDy -> ", jsonDy)
```

But getting the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 125, in <module>
    Main()
  File "a.py", line 18, in Main
    content = Read_json_file(eventFile)
  File "a.py", line 44, in Read_json_file
    jsonDy = json.load(fin)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

What I understand is here `u'` represents the `unicode` notation, but not sure how to read this file

`PS` : I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Try `json.loads()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a valid JSON structure.  It's a string representation of Python data structure.  The appropriate JSON structure would be:

```
{"Records": [{"eventVersion": "2.0"}]}
```

It looks like something is writing the JSON with the output of `json.loads` instead of `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import simplejson as json
w = json.dumps({u'Records': [{u'eventVersion': u'2.0', }]})
print json.loads(w)
```

or use:

```
import json
w = json.dumps({u'Records': [{u'eventVersion': u'2.0', }]})
print json.loads(w)
```

I have dumped to json to recreate the issue. You can just use `json.loads`

Comment: Here is my current code ;       `with open(jsonFile, 'rt') as fin:`
         `jsonDy = json.loads(fin.read())`...but getting the following error...`Traceback (most recent call last):
    content = Read_json_file(eventFile)
    jsonDy = json.loads(fin.read())
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
`

Comment: `json.loads(fin.read().replace("\'", '"'))` Can you try this and tell me?

Comment: Tried that....But, Getting the same error ; For the moment ; I have changed my file to have a valid JSON content...as @Lex have pointed out...that resolved my current road block with testing...

Comment: Might be helpful to someone in the same scenario...although not sure if this is an elegant solution. This works though....`json.loads(fin.read().replace("u'", '"').replace("'", '"'))`